# create functions for html hyperlinks to query database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, linq-to-sql

i have created a web application in `asp.net with C# and MySql Database at the backend` called simple online shopping,

I have created a `cascading dropdown horizontal navigation menu (navmenu) with unordered lists and html hyperlinks`. i have 2 pages `Homepage.aspx and ShowProducts.aspx`.

Navmenu contains the categories in an hierarchy and the products and category data is stored in databases. 
when a hyperlink is clicked on the navmenu i wanted the to show the products contained in the category in the ShowProducts.aspx
i have list item in unordered lists in navmenu in hierarchy of

1.Clothing
 1.1:Mens
    1.1.1:Shirts
    1.1.2:Trousers
    1.1.3:WinterWear

1.2:Womens
    1.2.1:Casual Wear
    1.2.2:Jeans
    1.2.3 Bags

I have wrote the hyperlinks as:

```
    <ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Clothing</a>
<ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Mens</a>
                        <ul class="sub2">
   <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Shirts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Mens Trousers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Jeans</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Winter wear</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Watches & Bags</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Footwear for men</a></li>
  </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Womens</a>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Sarees & Dresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Jewellery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Womens Jeans</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Womens Bags</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ShowProducts.aspx">Footwear for Women</a></li>
   </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

I am using Devart **linqconnect(Linq To MySql)**. some one told me to use **querystrings** to pass data between pages but it contains **images and data** so i wanted to use **repeaters** to show them in hiererchy. Could add an **onlick handler to`<a>`** tag so and write a **javascript function**
such as

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Function showproducts() {

```
     -- Linq code to retrieve products based on id --
```

}

could anybody suggest a good method or tell how can i achieve this.
thanks.. please help me on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Repeater to render list of links on your page. Add query string value like ShowProduct.aspx?id=1 to every link.

On ShowProduct Page, use linq to retrieve data from DB:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    var product = db.products.Where(p => p.id = id).FirstOrDefault();
    if(product != null)
    {
        //do your job here with product data
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my javascript method and hyperlinks in the homepage.aspx ok?

Comment: what for you need javascript onClick on link? what action you want to perform?

Comment: if I click on a hyperlink at a navmenu then it would fire a query to the database and the data will be carried to ShowProducts.aspx for to be displayed.. please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: javascript is executed on client side, you don't need to perform db operations on client side. code I showed you above is c# code, and need to be executed in code-behind on the server side on page_load event for example. please do more investigation on basic principles of creating asp.net pages. please vote or mark as resolved if it does help. thanks.

Comment: "Add query string value like ShowProduct.aspx?id=1 to every link" are talking about attribute "Id" of <a> tag that will give value ofShowProduct.aspx?id=1.

Comment: not the `A` tag `id`. but the `id` of your category or product, like you have Jeans, Watches & Bags, etc. Basically, I guess you wanna show more products after clicking on link, so you passing category `id` to next page, then using this 'id' you need to retrieve and show data from db.