# create a separated columns in asp.net c# using repeater or datalist using linqdatasource

Tags: asp.net, html, repeater, linqdatasource

I have created a database with table Category with categoryId,CategoryName, parentId and CategoryImage.

I am using Linqconnect(LinqtoMySql).

How could I display the categories and names using the Repeater or should I use datalist using linq datasource in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataList was designed for this purpose.

You will run into significant difficulties using a GridView or Repeater.

Use the [Repeat Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) property and the [Repeat Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) property.

```
 <asp:DataList id="MyDataList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" runat="server">
```

Of course, you'll need to set your DatasourceID and configure your datasource.

You can set the datasource from the codebehind if you wish.

```
 MyDataList.DataSource = MyDataTable
```

or

```
 MyDataList.DataSource = MyLinqQueryResults
```

**References**

- [DataList Repeat Direction Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx)
- [DataList Repeat Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx)
- [DataList (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7efxhktc.aspx)

Comment: repeater must be the first choice for this purpose, we can use CSS for repeating items Horizontally or Vertically

Comment: @SizS I strongly disagree. You are going to end up with very hackish CSS in order to execute a 4-column tabular layout, given a dynamic list of records to bind. The code will be very painful to maintain.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush you've a point, but we can give any layout to repeater and Repeater is fast as per compare to datalist, we can just use unordered list to that Horizontal View

Comment: @George W Bush:Which control i should use to display hierarchical data. please see my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363986/create-functions-for-html-hyperlinks-to-query-database/15364417#comment21710589_15364417

Comment: @VishalTorne For that, i would actually build a string in the Code-Behind using a StringBuilder, and then I would write it to a Literal control. The string would use nested Unordered Lists (HTML tag UL).

Comment: @GeorgeWBush Could give me an idea how i could do this.. not an entire solution.. please..